# MSMQ folder on Default Web Site

Tags: iis-7.5, msmq

What is the MSMQ folder under C:\inetpub\wwwroot ??

I'm assuming it stands for Microsoft Message Queuing.
What is the purpose of this folder under the Default Web Site on IIs 7.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subfolder is for Microsoft Message Queuing to use for messages sent over HTTP/HTTPS.
Don't delete or change this folder as it will break MSMQ.
If you don't require MSMQ on this web server then uninstall the feature through the control panel.

Comment: I doubt it will break MsMq, it will not, actually.

Comment: OK, to be more accurate, deleting this folder will break MSMQ over HTTP functionality.